# Find all complex irreps of $S_4\times C_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-presentation

> Find all complex irreducible representations of $S_4\times C_3$.

I know that $S_4\simeq\langle x,y,z\mid x^2=y^3=z^4=xyz=1\rangle$, $C_3\simeq\langle a\mid a^3\rangle$, hence, $$S_4\times C_3\simeq\langle a,x,y,z\mid a^3=x^2=y^3=z^4=xyz=1, ax=xa, ay=ya, az=za\rangle.$$ There are $15$ conjugacy classes in it, so, there are $15$ non-isomorphic complex irreps.

We can easily see that there are two one-dimensional reps: $(x,y,z,a)\mapsto(s,1,s,1)$ where $s\in\{\pm1\}$.

There are $13$ more irreps left.

Then... It gets harder. Can you please help me to find the other ones?

Comment: The irreps of $G\times H$ are essentially tensor products of irreps of $G$ and irreps of $H$. In this case, as $C_3$ is cyclic, just take an irrep of $S_4$ and make $a$ act as a cube root of unity.

Comment: Thank you, @AnginaSeng! It's a great hint!